# Count character values by group in a data.frame

Tags: r, dataframe, count, character

I have got a data.frame which contains two columns: `ID` and `Letter`. I need to summarize the `Letter` observations by `ID`.

Here an example:

```
df = read.table(text = 'ID Letter 
1   A
1   A
1   B
1   A
1   C
1   D
1   B
2   A
2   B
2   B
2   B
2   D
2   F
3   B
3   A
3   A
3   C
3   D, header = TRUE)
```

My output should be 3 data.frames as follows:

```
df_1

A  3
B  2
C  1
D  1

df_2

A  1
B  3
D  1
F  1 

df_3

A  2
B  1
C  1
D  1
```

It is just the count of the letters within each ID group. I think I could use a combination of the functions `table` and `aggregate`, but how?

Comment: Why is `table(df$ID, df$Letter)` insufficient? They won't be separate data.frames, though it is unclear why that is a need, rather than just your first guess at an output format.

Comment: If you need a `list` of `data.frames`, try `library(dplyr);lapply(split(df, df$ID), function(x) count(x, ID, Letter) %>% ungroup() %>% select(-ID))`

Comment: Or just `lapply(split(df$Letter, df$ID), function(x) as.data.frame(table(factor(x))))` without packages

Comment: Looks like it would be a dupe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks to @akrun, please see below how I managed to do the trick:

```
#create list of data.frames 

library(dplyr)

lst = lapply(split(df, df$ID), function(x) count(x, ID, Letter) %>% ungroup() %>% select(-ID))

lst = lapply(lst, function(y) y = as.data.frame(y)) #convert data into data.frames
```

Answer (score 0):

This will also work (with base R):

```
lapply(split(df, df$ID), function(x) subset(as.data.frame(table(x$Letter)), Freq != 0))
```